# Java getSubimage() Behavior

Tags: java, image

Okay, So I had a bit of a search and couldn't find this question asked anywhere, so hopefully it's not a duplicate.

I have this program that is just supposed to rearrange an image such that each corner moves to the opposite corner. Here's an illustration:
[The Expected Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC9NV.png)

Here's the Java code that I tried:

```
        //TL
        BufferedImage b1 = (b.getSubimage(0, 0, w/2, h/2));
        //TR
        BufferedImage b2 = (b.getSubimage(w/2, 0, w/2, h/2));
        //BL
        BufferedImage b3 = (b.getSubimage(0, h/2, w/2, h/2));
        //BR
        BufferedImage b4 = (b.getSubimage(w/2, h/2, w/2, h/2));

        Graphics2D g2d = b.createGraphics();

        //New TL
        g2d.drawImage(b4, 0, 0, null);
        //New TR
        g2d.drawImage(b3, w/2, 0, null);
        //New BL
        g2d.drawImage(b2, 0, h/2, null);
        //New BR
        g2d.drawImage(b1, w/2, h/2, null);
```

Where b is the bitmap I'm trying to rearrange. This code produces the following result:

[The Result I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRJQx.png)

I managed to fix the code by adding an extra line as such:

```
BufferedImage bTest = new BufferedImage(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = bTest.createGraphics();
```

And then using bTest instead of b.

So I guess my question is, What does getSubImage actually do? From what I can tell it just acts as a reference to the original BufferedImage instead of copying it when it's called.

I'd like to have a working version of this where it doesn't require an intermediate BufferedImage.

If anyone can offer some help, that'd be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think your first subimage has improper width and height arguments, you dont need to add x and y to them

Comment: In this case x, and y are both 0, and w and h are the width and height of the whole image. I'll fix the post though, thanks.

Comment: Method `getSubimage` returns new `BufferedImage` which uses the same data array, ColorModel, properties as original image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `b` is a `BufferedImage` - the [documentation of getSubimage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage-int-int-int-int-) says:

> Returns a subimage defined by a specified rectangular region. The returned BufferedImage **shares the same data array** as the original image.

That means that if you draw one *corner* on the opposite corner, it is also being *drawn* in the previously saved subimage.

You will need at least one temporary pixel, better one temporary corner image. IMHO best using another `BufferedImage` as you did (easier to understand).